# Homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

I think this is just an abuse of notation, but I want to be sure.

Consider the group homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is a group under integer addition and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, and define $\phi(x) = x \text{ (mod $3$)}$.

The notation $x \text{ (mod $3$)}$ is unfamilar to me. I know that what this function is trying to convey is "take the remainder of $x$ when dividing by $3$," but I have never seen it written this way. The proof that this is in fact a homomorphism looks similar:
\begin{align*}
\phi(x + y) = (x+y) \text{ (mod $3$)} = x \text{ (mod $3$)} + y \text{ (mod $3$)}.
\end{align*}
Not only does it abuse notation, but it's using the fact that in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, we have $\overline{a + b} = \overline{a} + \overline{b}$, and is therefore treating $x$ and $y$ not as integers (elements of an equivalence class) but representatives of the class itself. Then again, perhaps we're mapping *into* an equivalence class, so the mapping can be treated as $x \mapsto [x]$.

My question is, am I interpreting this correctly? Is this an abuse of notation? Is there possibly a better way to write this?

Comment: You are overthinking this slightly, and I think you realize this.  $x \bmod 3$ can be taken to mean the congruence class that $x$ belongs to, which may be represented by its remainder (but this rep is not unique).

Comment: So $x \text{ (mod $3$)}$ just means what I was calling $\overline{3}$?

Comment: In this context, yes.  There could be a slight abuse, but that’s how everyone interprets it in this case.

Comment: I (and many others) would write that simply $x\bmod 3$, taking $\bmod$ to be a binary operator defined by $$x\bmod y=x-y\lfloor x/y\rfloor$$ for $y\ne 0$.

Comment: When it’s integers you’re talking about, the notation $a\equiv b\pmod m$ goes back to Gauss, and it means nothing more and nothing less than that $b-a$ is a multiple of $m$. Properly, it’s read, “$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $m$.”

Answer (score 2):

Computer scientists and software engineers tend to use the phrase "$m \text{ mod } n$" for what mathematicians might call "the least residue of $m$ mod $n$." Here, to be really formal, "least residue" is the (set-theoretic only, not a homomorphism) section of the surjection
$$
\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}
$$
which takes the equivalence class $[a]$ to the least non-negative integer $b$ which is equivalent to $a$ mod $n$.

This abuse of notation is rarely harmful, although it does cause people to confuse each other; for instance, is it true that "2 mod 4 + 3 mod 4 equals 5 mod 4"?

Comment: Good, thanks. When I was teaching, I insisted that students *not* use the computer-science terminology, because it can’t be generalized to situations like quotient groups, or rings formed as $R/I$, where $I$ is some ideal of the original ring $R$.

Comment: Yes. The devil behind the details in viewing $\mathtt\{mod\}$ as a binary operator in programming languages is how to handle the cases of negative operands (and different programming languages disagree about this). In a general ring, there is no useful way to define such an operator.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}, n>1$ then "$x\text{ mod }n$" is, as you've correctly noted, the reminder of $x$ when divided by $n$.

Now $\mathbb{Z}_n$ can be (and often is) defined literally as $\{0,1,\ldots,n-2,n-1\}$, i.e. the set of all integers between $0$ and $n-1$. Next we define

$$x\oplus y:=(x+y)\text{ mod n}$$

where "$x+y$" is the standard integer addition. This is a well defined binary operation on $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and it turns $(\mathbb{Z}_n,\oplus)$ into an abelian group. And in fact there's a group epimorphism

$$\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}_n$$
$$x\mapsto x\text{ mod }n$$

It can be shown that the kernel of that epimorphism is $n\mathbb{Z}$ and so by the first isomorphism theorem our $\mathbb{Z}_n$ group is in fact isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore we can sort of replace "$x\text{ mod }n$" with "$x+n\mathbb{Z}$" and vice versa.

And so many authors use these symbols interchangeably. Which, I agree, can lead to confusion.

Comment: From personal experience, I know that this literal definition of ${\mathbb Z}_n$ that you mention leads to endless confusion among students learning group theory for the first time, and I do not understand why it is so common. (Many students  get multiplication and addition mixed up as well.) I prefer to define cyclic groups as $C_n = \{1,g,g^2,\ldots,g^{n-1}\}$, where you can think of $g$ as a rotation through $2\pi/n$. When you get on to quotient groups, you can prove that $({\mathbb Z},+)/(n{\mathbb Z},+) \cong C_n$, taking care to make the group operations clear on both sides.

Comment: Of course, for anyone who really understands what is going on, it is very convenient to abuse notation and use $\{ 0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ as elements of ${\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z}$.